# How to make EhCache reset the cache of the one-to-many relations a domain could have with other domains?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many, ehcache

**Database**

*`mother` table*

```
+-----------+------+
| mother_id | name |
+-----------+------+
|         1 | m1   |
|         2 | m2   |
+-----------+------+
```

*`child` table*

```
+----------+-----------+------+
| child_id | mother_id | name |
+----------+-----------+------+
|        1 |         1 | c1   |
|        2 |         1 | c2   |
|        3 |         2 | c3   |
+----------+-----------+------+
```

**Domains**

*Mother.java*

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "mother")
public class Mother {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mother")
    public List<Child> getChilds() {
        return this.childs;
    }

}
```

*Child.java*

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_mother", nullable = false)
    public Mother getMother() {
        return this.mother;
    }

}
```

**Daos**

*MotherDao.java*

```java
public interface MotherDao {

    @Cacheable(cacheName = "dao")
    public List<Mother> findAll();

    @TriggersRemove(cacheName = "dao")
    public void delete(Integer pk);

}
```

*MotherDao.java*

```java
public interface ChildDao {

    @Cacheable(cacheName = "dao")
    public List<Child> findAll();

}
```

**Conf**

*applicationContext.xml*

```xml
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />    
<bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />
```

*ehcache.xml*

```xml
<cache name="dao"
    eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="86400"
    imeToLiveSeconds="86400"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
```

**Issue**

```java
System.out.println(motherDao.findAll().size());
System.out.println(childDao.findAll().size());
motherDao.delete(1);
System.out.println(motherDao.findAll().size());
System.out.println(childDao.findAll().size());
```

Prints:

```
2
3
1
3
```

Instead of:

```
2
3
1
1
```

Since the deletion of the mother cascade-deleted two children, but the previous `childDao.findAll()` cached its results.

**Question**

How to make EhCache reset the cache of the one-to-many relations a domain could have with other domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use two caches for this.  Below is an example.

```
public interface ChildDao {

    @Cacheable(cacheName = "childDao")
    public List<Child> findAll();

}
```

Mother Dao.

```
public interface MotherDao {
    @Cacheable(cacheName = "motherDao")
    public List<Mother> findAll();

    @TriggersRemove(cacheName={"motherDao", "childDao"})
    public void delete(Integer pk);
}
```